# How to add 2 EditText entries into 1 rowitem of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-edittext

Like it is said in the title I want to add 2 entries of two different `EditText` into 1 listrowitem of my `ListView`.
Now I just can add one entry.

onCreateView of my fragment

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewswipeview);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextswipeView);
        final EditText editText2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button btnswipeview = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonswipeview);

        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        listItems.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnswipeview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View View) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "You clicked the button",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

My fragment xml *swipeview.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:id="@+id/swipeviewtitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeViewimage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#CFD8DC">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextswipeView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonswipeview"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CFD8DC">
        <ListView
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/listViewswipeview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:listitem="@layout/swipeviewrowitem"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerswipeview"

            android:entries="@array/day"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

my rowitem xml *swipeviewrowitem.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/new.workout"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/mainText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So if I make a entry in each of the two `EditText` objects the first one should be added to *android:id="@+id/mainText"* and the second one to *android:id="@+id/textView2"* of the listrowitem.
How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the stock `ArrayAdapter` with a built-in row layout:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
```

you'll probably want to create your own Adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter`, and pass it your custom row layout `R.layout.swipeviewrowitem`. You can add logic inside the custom Adapter to handle inputs to the `EditText`s.

Comment: can you make an example?